# "module has no attribute" in Python C module

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am trying to build [this old project](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eonboard/onboard/trunk/files) but `./setup.py build` shows this warning (not sure if related, could be normal):

```
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto: 
<the list of .c/.h files in Onboard/osk/>
```

and when I run `./onboard`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/....../onboard/./onboard", line 35, in <module>
    from Onboard.OnboardGtk import OnboardGtk as Onboard
  File "/home/....../onboard/Onboard/OnboardGtk.py", line 48, in <module>
    from Onboard.Keyboard        import Keyboard
  File "/home/....../onboard/Onboard/Keyboard.py", line 45, in <module>
    from Onboard.KeyboardPopups        import TouchFeedback
  File "/home/....../onboard/Onboard/KeyboardPopups.py", line 256, in <module>
    class LabelPopup(KeyboardPopupDrawable):
  File "/home/....../onboard/Onboard/KeyboardPopups.py", line 264, in LabelPopup
    _osk_util = osk.Util()
AttributeError: module 'Onboard.osk' has no attribute 'Util'
```

any ideas why it happens? I have never worked with C modules in Python before.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for [distutils-extra](https://pypi.org/project/distutils-extra-python/), to understand how to tell it about the C files and how to compile them and include the results in the project? yes, the problem is straightforward: the functionality is not there, because it has not been built.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel they are already listed in `setup.py` and they are built, there are `.o` files in `build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/Onboard/osk/`, and `build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/Onboard/osk.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.